# How to update existing cloudwatch ALARM using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I have some existing cloudwatch alarms in AWS , i have successfully exracted them and stored them in a list of dicts as follows:

```
[   {   'alarm_name': u'emsclassicldap_db_connections',
        'alarm_threshold': 200.0,
        'rds_name': u'emsclassicldap',
        'rds_type': u'db.m3.medium'},
    {   'alarm_name': u'smso-jenkins-40-shared_db_connections',
        'alarm_threshold': 266.0,
        'rds_name': u'smso-jenkins-40-shared',
        'rds_type': u'db.m3.medium'},
    {   'alarm_name': u'smso-jenkins-master-shared_db_connections',
        'alarm_threshold': 266.0,
        'rds_name': u'smso-jenkins-master-shared',
        'rds_type': u'db.m3.large'},
    {   'alarm_name': u'syd01-devops-deepali-shared_db_connections',
        'alarm_threshold': 266.0,
        'rds_name': u'syd01-devops-deepali-shared',
        'rds_type': u'db.m3.medium'}]
```

The above if a simple list and nothing fancy. Now i have some of the above alarms have some wrong `alarm_threshold` values which need to be updated with the following standard right ones:

```
thershold_db_t2_medium = 309  # 99% of 312
thershold_db_m3_medium = 316  # 99% of 320
thershold_db_m3_large  = 633  # 99% of 640
thershold_db_m3_xlarge = 1267  # 99% of 1280
thershold_db_m3_2xlarge= 2534  # 99% of 2560
thershold_db_m4_large  = 675  # 99% of 682
thershold_db_m4_xlarge = 1351  # 99% of 1365
thershold_db_m4_2xlarge=  2703  # 99% of 2730
```

I wrote the following to update the alarm

```
my_region_list=['ap-southeast-2']
def final_compare_update(w):
    for region in my_region_list:
        c = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region(region)
        for each_dict in w:
         #print each_dict['rds_type']
             if each_dict['rds_type']=="db.m2.medium" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_t2_medium:
                c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'],comparision='>=',threshold=thershold_db_t2_medium, period=300, evaluation_periods=3,statistic='Maximum')
                print "updated "+each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type']=="db.m3.medium" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m3_medium:
                c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m3_medium,period=300, evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type'] == "db.m3.large" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m3_large:
                c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m3_large, period=300,evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type'] == "db.m3.xlarge" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m3_xlarge:
                c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m3_xlarge,period=300,evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type'] == "db.m3.2xlarge" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m3_2xlarge:
                c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m3_2xlarge,period=300, evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type'] == "db.m4.large" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m4_large:
                 c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m4_large,period=300, evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                 print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type'] == "db.m4.xlarge" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m4_xlarge:
                 c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m4_xlarge,period=300, evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                 print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             elif each_dict['rds_type'] == "db.m4.2xlarge" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_m4_2xlarge:
                 c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m4_2xlarge,period=300, evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
                 print "updated " + each_dict['alarm_name']
             else:
                 print "Nothing was updated!"
```

This throws me ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_alarm.py", line 128, in <module>
    final = final_compare_update(w)
  File "update_alarm.py", line 88, in final_compare_update
    c.update_alarm(name=each_dict['alarm_name'], comparision='>=', threshold=thershold_db_m3_medium,period=300, evaluation_periods=3, statistic='Maximum')
TypeError: put_metric_alarm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

how to do so?

Comment: It's not the cause of your error, but FYI you have a small typo: `if each_dict['rds_type']=="db.m2.medium" and each_dict['alarm_threshold'] != thershold_db_t2_medium:` It is comparing m2 to t2. Also, you have several instances of "thershold" rather than "threshold".

Comment: Also `comparision` instead of `comparison`.

Comment: oh yeah sorry . got it

Answer (score 2):

The `update_alarm()` function takes a `MetricAlarm` object as input. Here is an example from the [boto documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/autoscale_tut.html):

```
from boto.ec2.cloudwatch import MetricAlarm
scale_up_alarm = MetricAlarm(
            name='scale_up_on_cpu', namespace='AWS/EC2',
            metric='CPUUtilization', statistic='Average',
            comparison='>', threshold='70',
            period='60', evaluation_periods=2,
            alarm_actions=[scale_up_policy.policy_arn],
            dimensions=alarm_dimensions)
cloudwatch.create_alarm(scale_up_alarm)
```

By the way, [it appears that](https://github.com/yyuu/botornado/blob/master/boto/ec2/cloudwatch/__init__.py) `update_alarm()` is an alias for `put_metric_alarm()`, which is why the error message mentioned that that funciton.

Here is one that worked for me, calling `update_alarm()`:

```
c.update_alarm(MetricAlarm(
            name='hello', namespace='AWS/EC2',
            metric='CPUUtilization', statistic='Average',
            comparison='<', threshold='60',
            period='60', evaluation_periods=2
            ))
```

Therefore, your code should be updated to:

```
c.update_alarm(MetricAlarm(
            name=each_dict['alarm_name'],
            comparison='>=',
            threshold=threshold_db_m3_medium,
            period=300,
            evaluation_periods=3,
            statistic='Maximum'
            ))
```